# Convert MyClass<SomeType> to MyClass<SomeOtherType>

Tags: c#, generics

Using C# 4.0. I want to convert an instance of `MyBuffer<int>` to an instance of `MyBuffer<float>`. The converter must be general enough to handle other basic types too.

**I want this (or equivalent solution) to work. HOW?**

```
var b1 = MyBuffer.Create(new int[100]);
var b2 = Convert.ChangeType(b1, typeof(MyBuffer<float>));
var b3 = Convert.ChangeType(b2, typeof(MyBuffer<byte>));
```

Consider the `MyBuffer` class:

```
public class MyBuffer
{
    public static MyBuffer<T> Create<T>(T[] buffer)
        where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible
    {
        return new MyBuffer<T>(buffer);
    }
}

public class MyBuffer<T> : IConvertible
    where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible
{
    public T[] Buffer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyBuffer()
    {
    }

    public MyBuffer(T[] buffer)
    {
        Buffer = buffer;
    }

    public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        if (conversionType == GetType())
            return this;

        // First problem: Determine if the type is MyBuffer<>.
        // if (conversionType == typeof(MyBuffer<>))
        {
            if (conversionType.IsGenericType && conversionType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
            {
                var bufferType = conversionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                dynamic newBuffer = Buffer.
                    Select(s => Convert.ChangeType(s, bufferType))
                    .ToArray();

                // Second problem: Our dynamic variable will produce an exception here.
                return MyBuffer.Create(newBuffer);
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // For completeness...
    //

    public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public byte ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public char ToChar(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DateTime ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public decimal ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public double ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public short ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public long ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public sbyte ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public float ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ushort ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public uint ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ulong ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In my code above there are two major problems that need to be solved:

1. How do you determine if a `Type` variable equals `SomeType<T>` for an arbitrary value of `T`?
2. Is it possible to call a templated function with `T` set to some `Type` variable?

Answer (score 4):

Since `MyBuffer<T>` very helpfully includes a constructor that takes the buffer to wrap as an argument, you can simply convert one buffer to another manually (very easy with LINQ) and create a new "converted" instance:

```
var b1 = MyBuffer.Create(new int[100]);
var b2 = MyBuffer.Create(b1.Buffer.Select(i => (float)i).ToArray());

// another way to do the same:
var b3 = MyBuffer.Create(b1.Buffer.Select(Convert.ToSingle).ToArray());
```

**Update:**

In order to assuage [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337917/convert-myclasssometype-to-myclasssomeothertype/16338009?noredirect=1#comment23418729_16338009)'s concern that I might have hidden intentions, here is how to do what the question asks with reflection, but of the more convenient form where the runtime does the digging in your place:

```
dynamic ConvertArray<T>(T[] input, Type target) {
    var result = Array.CreateInstance(target, input.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
    {
        result.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(input[i], target), i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This method allows you to do this:

```
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var strings = ConvertArray(ints, typeof(string));
foreach (var s in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", s.GetType(), s + " potato");
}
```

As is evident, `strings` behaves exactly like an array of strings. Of course being `dynamic` means that this particular array is never going to be able to mix with e.g. lambdas and the moral equivalent of reflection is still going on at runtime (only you don't see it). So it's not quite a free lunch, but it can prove useful at times.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to solve a more general problem here. Given an instance of `SomeClass<T>` how can you convert it to the same class but with a different type of `T`?

Comment: @l33t How do you expect to solve this for any two types, since the possible conversions are limited?

Comment: Any basic type; `byte`, `int`, `short`, `float`, `double` and their signed/unsigned counterparts. Perhaps also `bool`.

Comment: @l33t: Let's assume you have a method `Foo` that takes a `Type` as an argument (the type of buffer to convert to) and magically does what you want (returns a converted buffer). What would be the return type of the method? Your own attempt returns `object` -- how are you going to do anything with this `object`? What I 'm trying to say is: once you cross the line into reflection-land, you can never return back. Perhaps your requirements would be better met with a different design.

Comment: This answer is quite good, unless you have hidden intentions you didn't mention.

Comment: @Daniel: No, not really :-) But your comment inspired me to provide an option similar to what the OP was trying to achieve.

Comment: No, not you have hidden intentions, the author of the Question, lol!! But if it helped, ok....

Comment: Normally the askers hide their code and bring some simplified example to solve a single part of the whole.

Comment: @Daniel: I misread that because it was unaddressed. But yes, now that it's clear what you mean I agree.

Answer (score 1):

To the first problem:

```
if (conversionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyBuffer<>))
```

To the second problem:

```
//your method....
//....
if (conversionType.IsGenericType && conversionType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
{ //in fact you don't need this if in case the first problem is solved.

    var bufferType = conversionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Func<MyBuffer<object>> AuxMethod = BufferConversion<object>;
    return AuxMethod.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(bufferType).Invoke(this, null);            
 }
//....continue your method....


private MyBuffer<NewType> BufferConversion<NewType>()
{
    NewType[] MyNewArray = Buffer.Select(s => (NewType)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(NewType))).ToArray();
    return MyBuffer.Create(MyNewArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there. There is a great library for converting object types called AutoMapper.

http://automapper.codeplex.com/